# Fetching API Response from Eclipse Java not working

Tags: java, eclipse, api, okhttp

So I am trying to fetch this API response but have not been able to the problem. when I call this below function and debug it at a certain point it fetches the result but as soon as it crosses if block the response disappears. Look at the two images for reference.

[image: The image where the response is available]

[image: Response dissapears and gives me this error]

`public JsonObject getResult() {

```
    System.err.println(" Called getResult: "); 
    
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://localhost:7005/api/pools")
            .build();

    try (var response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        }

        ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
        String responseBodyString;

        if (responseBody != null) {
            responseBodyString = responseBody.string();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Response body is null");
        }

        JsonObject js = gson.fromJson(responseBodyString, JsonObject.class);

        return js;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("[ERROR] " + e.getMessage());
        // TODO Try again in x minutes
        System.out.print("No Response");
        System.err.println("[ERROR] No Response");
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

`

I am trying to debug each line-by-line code but still have not figured out what is the problem.

Comment: library is okhttp

Comment: Don't call `body()` multiple times. Calling it once consumes the data, subsequent calls will return an empty result. Your code does not call it twice, but your debug window evaluates that expression on every breakpoint and line you stop at. Remove the 2 expressions that call that method.

Comment: Correction: `string()` consumes and clears the data, not `body()`.

Comment: try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {

 if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
  throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
 }

 String responseBodyString = response.body().string();
 return gson.fromJson(responseBodyString, JsonObject.class)
}

the code is working fine but does not display the result

Comment: Please do not post Java code in comments, this makes the code unreadable. You can edit your post at any time and add the code there.